# Wasserstein distance and the Kantorovich-Rubinstein duality

Tags: reference-request, convex-optimization, optimal-transportation, exposition

The only few references I could find on this topic are either amateur blog posts (http://n.ethz.ch/~gbasso/download/A%20Hitchhikers%20guide%20to%20Wasserstein/A%20Hitchhikers%20guide%20to%20Wasserstein.pdf and https://vincentherrmann.github.io/blog/wasserstein/) or the 1000 page tome by Cedric Villani, (http://cedricvillani.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/preprint-1.pdf)

Is there any expository reference/lecture notes about this which is somewhere between the two kinds of references above? Any paper by maybe Cedric Villani himself which covers all these grounds?

Comment: You may want to look at the 2003 book by Villani not the 2008 tome; also, look at https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.07745

Comment: Thanks for the recent reference! By the 2003 book I guess you mean this one, "Topics in Optimal Transportation. Graduate Studies in Mathematics 58"

Comment: The book by Filippo Santambrogio (https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-20828-2) is also very well written.

Comment: https://optimaltransport.github.io/pdf/ComputationalOT.pdf looks also quite helpful.

Answer (score 5):

You might look at Chapter 3 of my book *Lipschitz Algebras* (second edition). The Banach space ${\rm Lip_0}(X)$ is already the dual of the space of finitely supported measures on $X$ satisfying $\mu(X) = 0$, equipped with Wasserstein distance (though I suppose it should then be called Arens-Eells distance). Going to Radon measures enlarges this space but you remain within the completion of the finitely supported measures, so its dual space doesn't change.

Answer (score 2):

Kantorovich himself wrote a very detailed exposition which constitutes Section 8.4 of  [Functional Analysis by Akilov and Kantorovich](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=664597)

Comment: But beware --- this section only exists in the second edition of that book!

Comment: @NikWeaver - the one I linked - but I should have specified that - thank you!